# How to use UserForm Values for multiple things

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2013, userform

I have UserForm1 which is a multipage userform and I am trying to access the information that was gathered through the form in a sub located in Module1. This sub will need to access several different values and do different things with those values so this is going to be a multipart question.

1. I have the below code in which I attempt to use one of the values as the upper limit of a For Next Loop. However the current problem is that when the code reaches this line it jumps to the Userform_Initialize routine.

---

```
For X = 1 To UserForm1.LocalOffer.Value
```

2. Second part of this question comes from inside the For Next loop from above. Where I have the below code. Which would ideally allow me to cycle through a series of similarly named Textboxes from the userform. Not even sure if that will work as the code keeps breaking before getting to that part.

---

```
Range("B" & X).Value = UserForm1.Controls("LocalTier" & Tier).Value
```

3. Last Part of this question if I have a Textbox in the userform that contains a date in the format 1/18/2015 is there a way for me to grab just a portion of that date say for instance just the Day or just the last digit of the year?

I am using Excel 2013 but the file will be ran on Excel 2007

***Edit:***
Turns out that problem 1 was fixed by not closing the userform with the X button but instead adding a line to hide the userform when you hit the last button. As it turns out my code for the second question worked just fine once i got past that. Only question left is the last one which I have no ideas on.

Comment: I used the button to display those as lines of code but it appears to have not worked if someone could edit that I would appreciate it.

Comment: It is because of the list it is in. Not elegant but I put in horizontal lines to address this. There could be other ways as well <code> blocks could also work

Comment: So, let's begin by the beginning: What's the value of UserForm1.LocalOffer.Value when the code reaches this line? I imagine that it's 1, so the code skips immediately this For Next structure. Check this, please.

Comment: The Value of LocalOffer is 4 and the Value of Tier is 9 and the Value of LocalTier9 is 50

Comment: Do the values of the userform just vanish when the userform is closed with the X?

Comment: Turns out that is a huge Yes!! OK so that gets me past problems 1 and 2 so now the only question is number 3. How to get a portion of a date from a userform textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from the comments, I see you don't need anymore to know about points 1 and 2, I will hence limit my answer to the point 3.

*Last Part of this question if I have a Textbox in the userform that contains a date in the format 1/18/2015 is there a way for me to grab just a portion of that date say for instance just the Day or just the last digit of the year?*

You can use either string manipulation, or date conversion. 
Let's assume the Textbox is called `myDateTextbox`

### String manipulation

Among the string manipulators that VBA provides, I would cite `Left()` and `Right()`.

For example:

```
last_digit_of_the_year = Right(myDateTextbox.Text, 1)
```

will return you the last character of the string. On the other hand:

```
first_digit = Left(myDateTextBox.Text,1)
```

will return you the first digit of the string. 
You can use the `Len(myDateTextBox.Text)` built-in to return the current length of the string.

### Date conversion

You can simply convert your string into date using the `CDate()` function. Please note this function will return an error if you pass an invalid string. If your textbox contains `24/01/1990`, you can first convert the string into a date:

```
myDate = CDate(myDateTextBox.Text)
```

Hence, you can retrieve day, month or year like this:

```
myYear = Year(myDate)
myMonth = Month(myDate)
myDay = Day(myDate)
```

Please note that *CDate recognizes date formats according to the locale setting of your system.*. Hence, if the format in the TextBox is not the same than the one of your system, then consider manipulating the string *before* to adapt it to the proper format. For example, if your system has settings DD/MM/YYYY and your textbox shows a MM/DD/YYYY type, you can "adjust it" as follows:

```
wrongFormat = myDateTextBox.Text
splittedDate = Split(wrongFormat,"/")
goodFormat = splittedDate(1) & "/" & splittedDate(0) & "/" splittedDate(2)
```

If `wrongFormat` was `1/18/2014` but your system would like to read it as `18/1/2014`, it's now fine because `goodFormat` will be equal to `18/1/2014` after the split and re-build.

Comment: Note: I would suggest the second method, i.e Date Conversion, because you can enjoy the stability of built-in functions for date manipulation while with string manipulation you always face more risks about the quality of the output.

Comment: This answer is so indepth and wonderful I can not thank you enough. With this I should be able to complete the project I have been working on for 13 hours straight. So ready for this to be done.

Comment: I was testing the Day() conversion in the immediate window to see if it would convert the 1st of the month to 1 or to 01 and I have a question. I type in Msgbox Day(1/1/2015) and it returned a msgbox saying 30. I changed the date to 1/5/2015 and it still returned a 30. Changed it to 2/5/2015 and still returned a 30.

Comment: @ChadPortman, you cannot write dates like that. The right way to write dates into the VBA code is by putting them between two hashtags. Try this, it will work fine: `MsgBox Day(#1/1/2015#)`, or `MsgBox(#1/5/2015#)`.

Comment: P.s. to be more precise, writing `1/1/2015` without hashtags is like writing `one divided by one divided by 2015`, which is something close to 0. Being `1` the first date of the system calendar (i.e. January 1st, 1900), your "almost 0" will be interpreted as being the 30 December 1899. That's why you see `30` as output of the day (this was just for learning purposes, remember: dates in VBA code always between two `#`) ;)

Comment: Thank you very much good to know. So I only need the hashtags if I am hard typing the date into VBA right I will not need those if I am using the value from a form correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69089/discussion-between-chad-portman-and-matteo-nnz).